# Masks and transparency

Tags: ruby, transparency, shoes, mask

I'm fairly new to Shoes and ran into two problems.

First I want to set a mask using a partially transparent png, like this:

```
mask do
    image "images/stencilMask.png"
end
```

Is this possible somehow or can only vector shapes be used?

Apart from that, I noticed a small bug(?) when trying to set a transparent color as a stroke on any kind of text, like this:

```
title "Hello", :stroke => rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
```

The transparency simply isn't applied. Am I doing anything wrong, or is this actually a bug?

Cheers and thanks for all answers

Answer (score 1):

Regarding masks, In my testing I've found it works with GIFs, but not PNGs on Windows:

```
Shoes.app do
    banner "hello this is a very long string", :top => 200
    mask do
        image "test.gif", :top => 0
    end
end
```

My test.gif was a 480x320 image with a solid oval in the middle. The rest of the image was transparent. This left the text appearing where the solid oval was in the image.

Regarding the stroke/transparency question. This is a bug/missing feature. See this question: [Make text transparent in Shoes.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214308/make-text-transparent-in-shoes-app)