# Make text transparent in Shoes.app

Tags: ruby, text, transparency, opacity, shoes

Is there a way in Shoes to have text show up transparent?
I have:

```
Shoes.app{
  para "Text", :stroke => rgb(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.5), :size => 100
}
```

But it's just showing up 100% red. I know opacity works for fill, does it also work for stroke?
(I am developing with Shoes Raisins Revision 1134 on Mac OS X 10.4.11)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha works on both stroke and fill, but not for text.  For example, this code will draw a 50% transparent blue circle over the text:

```
Shoes.app do
  para "Text", :stroke => rgb(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.5), :fill => rgb(0, 1.0, 0, 0.5), :size => 100
  stroke rgb(0,0,1.0,0.5)
  strokewidth 4
  nofill
  oval 10, 10, 50
end
```

Note that not only is the para's stroke not transparent, but neither is the fill.  To my knowledge there is no way to get transparent text out of Shoes, although I suppose if you made the text into a transparent image beforehand and loaded it, it might be transparent.  I haven't tried that, though, and even if it works, it's probably of limited usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround from the [_why archive](http://shoesrb.com/_why-archive/cut-holes-in-shoes-and-get-a-mask). You can use text on a mask layer and a transparent fill block to get actual transparent text.

```
Shoes.app do
  20.times do |i|
    strokewidth 4
    stroke rgb((0.0..0.5).rand, (0.0..1.0).rand, (0.0..0.3).rand)
    line 0, i * 4, 400, i * 4
  end

  mask do
    title "Shoes"
  end
end
```